# Update a deleted_at column on partition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Quick question, I'm trying to update a column only when there are duplicates(partition column > 1) in the table and have selected it based on partition concept, But the current query updates the whole table! please check the query below, Any leads would be greatly appreciated :)

```
UPDATE public.database_tag
SET deleted_at= '2022-04-25 19:33:29.087133+00'
FROM (
SELECT *,
row_number() over (partition by title order by created_at) as RN
FROM public.database_tag
ORDER BY RN DESC) X 
WHERE X.RN > 1
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You are not correlating rows from the derived table with the base table

Comment: Sure, Ik something is off, Would you please mind guiding me, I'm new to Complex queries, Need to get this done soon :/

Comment: Probably a common table expression might be a good way to go, identify duplicate rows there and update the common table expression.

Comment: Unfortunately afaik Postgres does not support updatable CTEs @VynlJunkie

Comment: Is there any unique row ID on this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every row have unique ID it can be done like below.

```
UPDATE database_tag 
SET deleted_at= '2022-04-25 19:33:29.087133+00'
WHERE <some_unique_id> in (
  select <some_unique_id> from (
     SELECT <some_unique_id>,
       row_number() over (partition by title order by created_at) as RN
     FROM public.database_tag
  ) X 
   WHERE X.RN > 1
)
```

Or we can reverse query to update all but set of ID's

```
UPDATE database_tag
SET deleted_at= '2022-04-25 19:33:29.087133+00'
WHERE <some_unique_id> not in (
  select distinct on (title)
     <some_unique_id> from database_tag
  order by title, created_at
  )
```

Comment: Thanks very much @kadet, It really worked, saved me some time, Cheers :)